# Jibx - not able to run with JDK11

Tags: java-11, jibx

Has someone been able to run jibx on Java11 ?

- Jibx 1.3.1
- Bcel 6.4.1

I saw some posts saying that it's running for JDK9, nothing for JDK11.

I have the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.jibx:maven-jibx-plugin:1.3.1:bind (default) on project phoebus-suc-data: Superclass java.lang.Object of class org.jibx.runtime.Utility not found -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well with the below version. I verified it. Its working for me now.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <directory>src/main/jibx-bindings</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*binding*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
                    <version>6.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```